# Wordpress syntax error, eval()'d code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and now I have following error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /www/htdocs/w006fce9/endax/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()'d code on line 3

The source code:

```
if( ! function_exists('will_bontrager_insert_php') )
{

    function will_bontrager_insert_php($content)
    {
        $will_bontrager_content = $content;
        preg_match_all('!\[insert_php[^\]]*\](.*?)\[/insert_php[^\]]*\]!is',$will_bontrager_content,$will_bontrager_matches);
        $will_bontrager_nummatches = count($will_bontrager_matches[0]);
        for( $will_bontrager_i=0; $will_bontrager_i<$will_bontrager_nummatches; $will_bontrager_i++ )
        {
            ob_start();
            eval($will_bontrager_matches[1][$will_bontrager_i]);
            $will_bontrager_replacement = ob_get_contents();
            ob_clean();
            ob_end_flush();
            $will_bontrager_content = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($will_bontrager_matches[0][$will_bontrager_i],'/').'/',$will_bontrager_replacement,$will_bontrager_content,1);
        }
        return $will_bontrager_content;
    } # function will_bontrager_insert_php()

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'will_bontrager_insert_php', 9 );

} # if( ! function_exists('will_bontrager_insert_php') )
```

I cannot find the error. Can someone help me?

Best regards,

Mustafa

Comment: what does line 47 and 48 of insert_php.php file say? I cannot see error in this code either

Comment: I highly recommend not using this plugin.  Any code using the `eval` function is highly susceptible to abuse if your site is compromised.  ie some one brute forces a low level account that can only create posts ... they see this plugin is available now they can run any code they want on your site.